# How to pass children and type to classnames library in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to Nextjs and taking this tutorial https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/styling-tips.

To use the classnames library, this module is created "alert.js"

```
import styles from './alert.module.css'
import cn from 'classnames'

export default function Alert({ children, type }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={cn({
        [styles.success]: type === 'success',
        [styles.error]: type === 'error'
      })}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

css module "alert.module.css"

```
.success {
  color: green;
}
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Now I am try to use this in Layout.js using:

`import Alert from './alert.js'` to import alert module

`<Alert success>test</Alert>` to insert and test an Alert element

However, in the HTML output this looks like:

`<div class="">test</div>` where the class is blank. I was expecting to be class="success" (I am not sure)

I think I am not properly passing the "type" correctly to Alert. Can someone show me the correct usage in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `classnames` package works, but you wrote that

```js
[styles.success]: type = 'success'
```

theoretically, You're saying, if variable `type`'s type is a string and its value is `success` then use `styles.success` class, but you passed success attribute without value

```js
<Alert success>test</Alert>
```

you have to give it a value like:

```js
<Alert type="success">test</Alert>
```

which is OK, but you can do that in a way that makes more sense, I can think of two ways:

1. if your alert has only two states, then instead of `success` or `error` strings, pass type as a boolean, if it was `true` or just exists without any value as you did, then `Alert` component should show success, otherwise it should show error message, i.e:

```js
export default function Alert({ chidren, type }){
  return (
    <div className={type ? styles.success : styles.error}>
    {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

2. if your alert has more than two states, for example it has **success**, **error** and **warning** , then pass `type` but give it values

- if alert type was success pass success as string `<Alert type="success">test</Alert>`
- if alert type was error pass error as string `<Alert type="error">test</Alert>`
- if alert type was warning pass warning as string `<Alert type="warning">test</Alert>`

Comment: thanks for the answer...classnames worked with <Alert type="success">test</Alert>. I will mark your answer as the right answer. <Alert success="success">test</Alert> didnt work so please change it to <Alert type="success">test</Alert> so someone else looking for this dosen't get misdirected.

Comment: this is the html output  using classnames library <div class="alert_success__3i9Ae">testfgdfg</div>...it helps by avoiding class name collisions by creating class like "alert_success__3i9Ae" and applying the correct css to it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I hope it helped. I saw you used `name.module.css` notation, so if you're using `create-react-app` or parcel, you can just forget about `classnames` package as those two are doing the same thing for you out-of-the-box if you use that notation.